# How can I target and change CSS border property of a div with a presenter-menu_avatar class on a mouseOver in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, properties

How can I target and change CSS border property of a div in my HTML with a presenter-menu_avatar class on a mouseOver in Angular application? I have tried [ngClass], however, it seems I am not implementing it right as it makes the whole app constantly crash.

component.ts:

```
export class Component {
  private isPopupDisplayed: boolean = false;

  onClick() {
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.isPopupDisplayed = true;
  }

  onClickedOutside(event) {
    this.isPopupDisplayed = false;
  }

}
```

CSS:

```
.presenter-menu {
  background: $accent-color;
  &_avatar {
    &:after {
      border: 0.25rem solid $accent-color;
    }

  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="isPopupDisplayed" >
        <ul class="popup" (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)">
            <li><a>My Details</a></li>
            <li><a>Sign out</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>

    <div class="presenter-menu_avatar" (click)="onClick()" >
        <img [src]="avatarUrl">
    </div>
```

Comment: The syntax of the `ngClass` is `<div [ngClass]="{'active': isActive, 'disabled': isDisabled}">` (`isActive` and `isDisabled` are both public boolean variables)

Comment: Could you please extend your answer for this particular example?

Comment: Can you please show us the code that did not work when you tried `ngClass` by editing your answer?